# How to use Touch () functions?

Tags: sql, questdb

I would like to know how to use Touch functions for Tables in QuestDB SQL? It would be great if an example is provided for the same!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any documentation for this function including it's usage.
However a look at the [tests](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/blob/master/core/src/test/java/io/questdb/griffin/engine/functions/TouchTableFunctionTest.java) and the [code](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/questdb/griffin/engine/functions/table/TouchTableFunctionFactory.java) gives some hints:

- The function takes a cursor as a parameter like:

  touch(select * from x where k in '1970-01-22');
- The function returns a string with 3 parts:

  - data_pages
  - index_key_pages
  - index_value_pages
  - Eg: {"data_pages": 4, "index_key_pages":1, "index_values_pages": 1}
  - Refer [this](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/indexes/) page for more details about indexes in questdb
- Example on how to use the touch function based on the tests for this function:

  - with index:

    create table x as
    (select
    rnd_geohash(40) g,
    rnd_double(0)*100 a,
    rnd_symbol(5,4,4,1) b,
    timestamp_sequence(0, 100000000000) k
    from long_sequence(20)), index(b) timestamp(k) partition by DAY;

    select touch(select * from x where k in '1970-01-22');

[image: with index touch query]